# Is there a way to integrate Node.js into the kernel core so that the system has this node running as a module.?

Tags: kernel, nodejs

I want to integrate node.js into the kernel as a module. So that i could develop a common html+js+css app as a desktop app. How can this be done ? It would be nice if ubuntu had this feature.

Comment: Why would that need a kernel module? O.o

Comment: @muru : wont that be great ? To get more kernel based control over node's excecution. Or is there any other way ? pls suggest. Bit of a newbie to kernel dev. :)

Comment: Sounds terrible to me. Code the runs in the kernel should a) need to be in the kernel and b) very stable. I don't see how a completely userspace app needs a kernel module, that's all. You can simply develop your html+js+CSS app and depend on nodejs.

Comment: @muru : I was playign with node-webkit. It is an app runtime based on Chromium and node.js. The thing is everytime i had to run this app, it needed node.js installed. I wanted to remove this dependency. With desktops that had no node.js, it became a neccessity to go and download node.js everytime. So i thought instead of putting it in the userspace, why not make it inbuilt within the system itself. so now our system has node within it [this part i dont know. maybe in kernel. maybe above it.] Hope your getting ?

Comment: I see. No, I still think it is a terrible idea. a) A kernel module would still need to be installed independently. b) That's how things work and dependency resolution systems like `dpkg` have been created for. If Nodejs, why not Python, or, Java, or Golang, in the kernel as well? Next, if you do add them, why not add your app in the kernel as well? You should, instead, consider packaging your software better. In Windows, provide a nodejs installer with yours. In Linux distros, make your package depend on nodejs, so that the package manager handles it.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to do this. In general, having it as a kernel module will pose a significant security risk, because nodejs is executing a user application and if there are problems with that application, it will be very easy to exploit them. As well, kernel modules are supposed to be "very tight and tidy" in terms of their runtime behavior, many/most nodejs application certainly will not be.

I might be wrong, but I am not aware of any other software similar to nodejs that runs as a kernel module (java, django, etc.).

At the same time, I do not think you are going to gain any real benefits compared to running it as a daemon.

Comment: hmm.... I wanted node within the system somehow so that i dont have to go and install it.

Comment: But even if it was a kernel module, you will still need to install it, enable it, and possibly configure it - many of the upstream kernel modules require these steps, e.g., the nfs server. So I see no significant saving there.